# Players unable to rejoin lobbies after disconnecting once Unity Relay & Lobbies

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

so iv been having trouble trying to reconnect clients to the same lobby after they leave.
Creating a public lobby then joining it using QuickJoinLobbyAsync seems to work just fine, but if a client leaves a lobby they unable to reconnect to that same lobby. when trying to connect again I get this error : "[Lobby]: NoOpenLobbies, (16006). Message: failed to find any open lobbies matching the search criteria"

The following script is attached to a GameObject that is active in the hierarchy.

I have buttons that when pressed activate certain functions such as CreateAMatch()

There are 2 scenes in my project, Multiplayer and MainMenu, This script is used in MultiPlayer

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Unity.Netcode;
using Unity.Services.Authentication;
using Unity.Services.Core;
using Unity.Services.Lobbies;
using Unity.Services.Lobbies.Models;
using Unity.Services.Relay;
using Unity.Services.Relay.Models;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using Unity.Netcode.Transports.UTP;

public class GameManagerV2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static GameManagerV2 _instance;
    public static GameManagerV2 Instance => _instance;

    public RelayHostData _hostData;
    public RelayJoinData _joinData;

    public string joinCode;

    public string lobbyId;

    public string lobbyjoinCode;


    public UnityAction<string> UpdateState;
    // Notify Match found
    public UnityAction MatchFound;
    public List<string> lobbyPlayers = new List<string>();

    
    async void Awake()
    {


    }

    async void Start()
    {



        // UnityServices.InitializeAsync() will initialize all services that are subscribed to Core.
        await UnityServices.InitializeAsync();
        Debug.Log(UnityServices.State);

        SetupEvents();

        await SignInAnonymouslyAsync();

        NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientConnectedCallback += ClientConnected;
        NetworkManager.Singleton.OnClientDisconnectCallback += ClientDisconnected;

    }

    // Setup authentication event handlers if desired
    void SetupEvents()
    {
        AuthenticationService.Instance.SignedIn += () => {
            // Shows how to get a playerID
            Debug.Log($"PlayerID: {AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId}");

            // Shows how to get an access token
            Debug.Log($"Access Token: {AuthenticationService.Instance.AccessToken}");

        };

        AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInFailed += (err) => {
            Debug.LogError(err);
        };

        AuthenticationService.Instance.SignedOut += () => {
            Debug.Log("Player signed out.");
        };

        AuthenticationService.Instance.Expired += () =>
        {
            Debug.Log("Player session could not be refreshed and expired.");
        };
    }

    async Task SignInAnonymouslyAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            await AuthenticationService.Instance.SignInAnonymouslyAsync();
            Debug.Log("Sign in anonymously succeeded!");

            // Shows how to get the playerID
            Debug.Log($"PlayerID: {AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId}");

        }
        catch (AuthenticationException ex)
        {
            // Compare error code to AuthenticationErrorCodes
            // Notify the player with the proper error message
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
        catch (RequestFailedException ex)
        {
            // Compare error code to CommonErrorCodes
            // Notify the player with the proper error message
            Debug.LogException(ex);
        }
    }

    private void ClientConnected(ulong id)
    {
        // Player with id connected to our session

        Debug.Log("Connected player with id: " + id);

        UpdateState?.Invoke("Player found!");
        MatchFound?.Invoke();
    }

    private async void ClientDisconnected(ulong id)
    {
            lobbyId.ToString();

            string playerId = AuthenticationService.Instance.PlayerId;

            Debug.Log("The Player : " + playerId + " Has left from lobby : " + lobbyId);

            await LobbyService.Instance.RemovePlayerAsync(lobbyId, playerId);


    }

    public struct RelayHostData
    {
        public string JoinCode;
        public string IPv4Address;
        public ushort Port;
        public Guid AllocationID;
        public byte[] AllocationIDBytes;
        public byte[] ConnectionData;
        public byte[] Key;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// RelayHostData represents the necessary informations
    /// for a Host to host a game on a Relay
    /// </summary>
    public struct RelayJoinData
    {
        public string JoinCode;
        public string IPv4Address;
        public ushort Port;
        public Guid AllocationID;
        public byte[] AllocationIDBytes;
        public byte[] ConnectionData;
        public byte[] HostConnectionData;
        public byte[] Key;
    }

    public async void CreateAMatch()
    {

        Debug.Log("Creating a new lobby...");

        UpdateState?.Invoke("Creating a new match...");

        int maxConnections = 20;

        try 
        {

            Allocation allocation = await Relay.Instance.CreateAllocationAsync(maxConnections);
            _hostData = new RelayHostData
            {
                Key = allocation.Key,
                Port = (ushort)allocation.RelayServer.Port,
                AllocationID = allocation.AllocationId,
                AllocationIDBytes = allocation.AllocationIdBytes,
                ConnectionData = allocation.ConnectionData,
                IPv4Address = allocation.RelayServer.IpV4
            };

            Debug.Log("Key is " + allocation.Key);

            _hostData.JoinCode = await Relay.Instance.GetJoinCodeAsync(allocation.AllocationId);


            CreateLobbyOptions options = new CreateLobbyOptions();
            string lobbyName = "new_lobby";
            int maxPlayers = 20;
            options.IsPrivate = false;

            options.Data = new Dictionary<string, DataObject>()
            {
                {
                    "joinCode", new DataObject(
                        visibility: DataObject.VisibilityOptions.Public,
                        value: _hostData.JoinCode)

                },

            };

            Lobby lobby = await LobbyService.Instance.CreateLobbyAsync(lobbyName, maxPlayers, options);

            lobbyId = lobby.Id;


            Debug.Log("This Is the RAW Lobby Id : " + lobby.Id);

            Debug.Log("This Is the RAW Join Code: " + _hostData.JoinCode);

            StartCoroutine(HeartbeatLobbyCoroutine(lobby.Id, 15));


            NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetRelayServerData(
                _hostData.IPv4Address,
                _hostData.Port,
                _hostData.AllocationIDBytes,
                _hostData.Key,
                _hostData.ConnectionData);


            NetworkManager.Singleton.StartHost();

            UpdateState?.Invoke("Waiting for players...");

            Debug.Log("Match Created! ");

        }
        catch (LobbyServiceException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            throw;


        }

    }



    IEnumerator HeartbeatLobbyCoroutine(string lobbyId, float waitTimeSeconds)
    {
        var delay = new WaitForSecondsRealtime(waitTimeSeconds);
        while (true)
        {
            Lobbies.Instance.SendHeartbeatPingAsync(lobbyId);
            Debug.Log("Lobby Heartbit");
            yield return delay;
        }

    }


    public async void JoinACreatedMatch()
    {

            try
            {
                QuickJoinLobbyOptions options = new QuickJoinLobbyOptions();


                options.Filter = new List<QueryFilter>()
            {
                new QueryFilter(
                    field: QueryFilter.FieldOptions.MaxPlayers,
                    op: QueryFilter.OpOptions.GE,
                    value: "20")
            };


                var lobby = await LobbyService.Instance.QuickJoinLobbyAsync(options);

                string joinCode = lobby.Data["joinCode"].Value;

                lobbyId = lobby.Id;
                
                lobbyjoinCode = lobby.Data["joinCode"].Value;

                JoinAllocation allocation = await Relay.Instance.JoinAllocationAsync(joinCode);
                _joinData = new RelayJoinData
                {
                    Key = allocation.Key,
                    Port = (ushort)allocation.RelayServer.Port,
                    AllocationID = allocation.AllocationId,
                    AllocationIDBytes = allocation.AllocationIdBytes,
                    ConnectionData = allocation.ConnectionData,
                    HostConnectionData = allocation.HostConnectionData,
                    IPv4Address = allocation.RelayServer.IpV4
                };

            
            NetworkManager.Singleton.GetComponent<UnityTransport>().SetRelayServerData(
                _joinData.IPv4Address,
                _joinData.Port,
                _joinData.AllocationIDBytes,
                _joinData.Key,
                _joinData.ConnectionData,
                _joinData.HostConnectionData);
            

            // Finally start the client
            NetworkManager.Singleton.StartClient();

            }
            catch (LobbyServiceException e)
            {
                Debug.Log(e);
            }



    }


}
```

As for the disconnect function:

This script is attached to the player prefab.

inside of void update.

```
        if (IsOwner)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.O))
            {
                NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();
                SceneManager.LoadScene("MultiPlayer");
            }
        }
```

PS: I'm very new to programing and unity in general

At first i noticed i had no OnClientDisconnectCallback method, and so i promptly added that. later i added a disconnect function to the client so that upon a key press the client would end its connection "NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();" i thought that this would both indicate to the host that a client had left, and the client was no longer connected.

Answer (score 1):

So for me... it turns out I was using a "ConnectionNotificationManager.cs"  that I then Destroyed on the client side after connection.

This resulted in the client callback registered to the NetworkManager becoming null.  Then I did not get my call back.

Perhaps you are unregistering your callback or destroying the object.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you are disconnecting the Relay, but not leaving the lobby.

https://docs.unity.com/lobby/en/manual/leave-a-lobby

Try using `RemovePlayerAsync`.